# hide link until the hover div

Tags: html, css, asp.net

How can I hide the link [Add|Edit] and when I hover the handle, the link will appear beside as shown as picture. When didn't hover , it should just show 001-001 Item 6 for example.

```css
    .dd-list { display: block; position: relative; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; }
    .dd-handle { display: block; height: 30px; margin: 5px 0; padding: 5px 10px; color: #334151; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; border:  1px solid rgba(255,255,255, 0.3);
       background-color: #F1F2F9;
        box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .dd-handle:hover { color: #000;  }
    a {
        color: #8760fb;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    a:hover {
        color: #7c59e6;
      }
```

```html
  <ol class="dd-list">
    <li class="dd-item" data-id="6">
    <div class="dd-handle">Item 6 [<a href="#Add.aspx">Add</a>|<a href="Edit.aspx"> Edit</a>]</div>
    </li>
    <li class="dd-item" data-id="7">
    <div class="dd-handle">Item 7 [<a href="#Add.aspx">Add</a>|<a href="Edit.aspx"> Edit</a>]</div>
    </li>
    <li class="dd-item" data-id="8">
    <div class="dd-handle">001-000 Equipment [<a href="#Add.aspx">Add</a>|<a href="Edit.aspx"> Edit</a>] </div>
    </li>
    </ol>
```

[Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWsNy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you will get solution check this working snippet

```css
.dd-list { display: block; position: relative; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; }
    .dd-handle { display: block; height: 30px; margin: 5px 0; padding: 5px 10px; color: #334151; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; border:  1px solid rgba(255,255,255, 0.3);
       background-color: #F1F2F9;
        box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .dd-handle:hover .hide{ color: #000;display:inline
    }
   
    .hide{
    color: #000;display:none
    }
     
    a {
        color: #8760fb;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    a:hover {
        color: #7c59e6;
      }
```

```html
<ol class="dd-list">
    <li class="dd-item" data-id="6">
    <div class="dd-handle">Item 6 <span class="hide">[<a  href="#Add.aspx">Add</a>|<a href="Edit.aspx"> Edit</a>]</span></div>
    </li>
    <li class="dd-item" data-id="7">
    <div class="dd-handle">Item 7 <span class="hide">[<a  href="#Add.aspx">Add</a>|<a  href="Edit.aspx"> Edit</a>]</span></div>
    </li>
    <li class="dd-item" data-id="8">
    <div class="dd-handle">001-000 Equipment <span class="hide">[<a  href="#Add.aspx">Add</a>|<a  href="Edit.aspx"> Edit</a>]</span> </div>
    </li>
    </ol>
```